# Sed command to search by regex in file

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep, regex-group

I need to get a number of version from file. My version file looks like this:

```
#define MINOR_VERSION_NUMBER    1
```

I try to use sed command:

```
VERSION_MINOR=`sed -i -e 'MINOR_VERSION_NUMBER\s+\([0-9]+\).*/\1/p' $WORKSPACE/project/common/version.h`
```

but I get error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: extra characters after command
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to modify the version.h file? If not, don't use `-i`.

Answer (score 1):

The "address" that selects matching lines needs to be enclosed in `/.../` (or `\X...X` for any X).

```
sed -ne '/MINOR_VERSION_NUMBER/{ s/.*\([0-9]\).*/\1/;p }'
```

Don't use `-i`, it changes the file in place and doesn't output anything.

The more common way would be to use `awk` to find the line and extract the wanted column:

```
awk '(/MINOR_VERSION_NUMBER/){print$3}'
```

Comment: I dont understand. When I use `/MINOR_VERSION_NUMBER/` I get whole file as result

Comment: @Kucharsky That is because `sed` prints the whole file as default. `sed` is not a tool to select parts from files, it is a file editor. Tools such as `grep` and `awk` operate on files and can perform various actions which are more in the _select_ area.

Comment: with `sed` you need `-n` to suppress printing of every line by default. Then you need a `p` command to explicitly tell it to print when you want it to. You can do `s///` edits on the line first.

Answer (score 1):

using grep

```
grep MINOR_VERSION_NUMBER  | grep -o '[0-9]*$'
```

Demo :

```
$echo "#define MINOR_VERSION_NUMBER    1"  |  grep -o '[0-9]*$' 
1
$echo "#define MINOR_VERSION_NUMBER    1123"  |  grep -o '[0-9]*$'
1123
$
```

Comment: This fails if the #define line ends with a comment or with extra spaces. choroba's answer is better in that respect.

Comment: Answer is based on user provided input.

Comment: Can you guarantee there won't ever be an invisible extra space after the version number? Developers are not error-proof. Especially when this is not an error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a correction of your attempt. Change your line:

```
VERSION_MINOR=`sed -i -e 'MINOR_VERSION_NUMBER\s+\([0-9]+\).*/\1/p' $WORKSPACE/project/common/version.h`
```

into:

```
VERSION_MINOR=`sed -n -e '/^#define\s\+MINOR_VERSION_NUMBER\s\+\([0-9]\+\).*/ s//\1/p' $WORKSPACE/project/common/version.h`
```

This can be made more readable with GNU `sed`'s `-r` option:

```
VERSION_MINOR=`sed -n -r -e '/^#define\s+MINOR_VERSION_NUMBER\s+([0-9]+).*/ s//\1/p' $WORKSPACE/project/common/version.h`
```

As stated by choroba, awk would be more suited than sed for this kind of processing (see his answer).

However, here is another solution using bash's `read` builtin, together with GNU grep:

```
read x x VERSION_MINOR x < <(grep -F -w -m1 MINOR_VERSION_NUMBER $WORKSPACE/project/common/version.h)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
VERSION_MINOR=$(echo "#define MINOR_VERSION_NUMBER    1" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3)
```